# How to print a std::map after throwing a runTime error

Tags: c++, c++11

I would like to throw and `runTime` error in a function and afterwards print a map.

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

class myClass
{
    public:

        static bool storeInMap(const std::string& name, int value)
        {
            if(myMap.find(name) == myMap.end())
            { 
                myMap[name] = value;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        static void lookup(const std::string& name)
        {
            auto it = myMap.find(name);
            if (it != myMap.end())
            {
                std::cout << "Found " << std::endl;
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "Not found. \n \
                             Available are: \n " << std::endl;
            }
        }

    private:
        static std::map<std::string, int> myMap;
};

std::map<std::string, int> myClass::myMap;

int main()
{
    myClass::storeInMap("one", 1);
    myClass::storeInMap("two", 2);
    myClass::lookup("one");
    myClass::lookup("three");

    return 0;
}
```

The first 2 lines in main will store the entry for `"one"` and `"two"`.
The third line is going to lookup in the `map` the entry `"one"` and print `"Found"`.
The forth line will should throw a `runTime error` and print all entries in `myMap`.
In the case:

```
Not found 
Available are:
"one"
"two"
```

However I do not know how to put the map in a `runTime error`, and would appreciate the help!

Best regards

Comment: *The forth line will should throw a runTime error* -- As your code does not show this, did you attempt to write the code to just throw the error?  What issues did you have?

Comment: I dont know what syntax to use to make this work. I tried writting the `operator<<` but I am not able to pass this to `throw runtime_error("some message");`

Comment: @mysticSnake You can't put a map in a `runtime_error`, but what you can do is derive a class from `runtime_error` and put the map in that. Does that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're going for

```
else
{
    std::string error_msg = "\n\nNot found!\nAvailable are:\n";
    for(auto& n : myMap)
    {
        error_msg += n.first + "\n";
    }
    throw std::runtime_error(error_msg.c_str());
}
```

Comment: I'd add that it would be better to use `std::stringstream` instead of adding values to `std::string`